# PowerMockRunner causes ExceptionInInitializerError when running trivial test

Tags: java, maven, easymock, powermock

I cannot run a very simple test class using the Powermock test runnner.  It causes an ExceptionInInitializerError.  It looks to be a problem with the dependencies on the classpath, however, I have tried a few variants of the dependency versions, but all of them cause the same error.  How can I get this simple test to pass when using the Powermock test runner?

The test code:

```
package net.solasistim.hello;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class HelloTest {
    @Test
    public void testMain() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Project POM:

```xml
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>net.solasistim.hello</groupId>
  <artifactId>hello</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <powermock.version>1.5</powermock.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
      <version>${powermock.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-api-easymock</artifactId>
      <version>${powermock.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>  
   <dependency>
      <groupId>cglib</groupId>
      <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
      <version>3.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>  
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
      <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
      <version>4.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>  
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Running `mvn clean compile test` causes the following output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: net.solasistim.hello.HelloTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.097 sec <<< FAILURE!
initializationError(net.solasistim.hello.HelloTest)  Time elapsed: 0.007 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.powermock.api.extension.proxyframework.ProxyFrameworkImpl.isProxy(ProxyFrameworkImpl.java:29)
        at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getUnmockedType(WhiteboxImpl.java:1783)
        at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getType(WhiteboxImpl.java:2237)
        at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.checkArgumentTypesMatchParameterTypes(WhiteboxImpl.java:2191)
        at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.findMethodOrThrowException(WhiteboxImpl.java:938)
        at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:882)
        at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:859)
        at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:466)
        at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.registerProxyframework(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:154)
        at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.getPowerMockTestListenersLoadedByASpecificClassLoader(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:107)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:143)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:39)
        at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:217)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:59)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
        at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:33)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter.<init>(DebuggingClassWriter.java:49)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.getClassVisitor(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:30)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:24)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:144)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:116)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
        at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)
        ... 38 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerMock and the newest cglib seem to not get along with each other. I can't tell you exactly the reason, but if you **downgrade from 3.0 to 2.2.2**, it should work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```